# Long TTFB on WP site, I tried everything with no luck

Tags: wordpress

So, here is the deal. I have a long TTFB (waiting time) at my WP site. Around 1000-3000ms.
The website is pretty light, using Elementor pro (Hello theme) and it loads fast (after the TTFB time).

Thing is, the TTFB is the same on my localhost as well as on the live server (I am on SiteGround with Cloudflare's CDN) so I am guessing there is probably a problem in my DB? I Don't know.

I already tried disabling all plugins, changing themes, caching plugins, and all other advice I could find on google including image compression, minifying CSS, JS, gzip etc.

On optimized sites I can see the TTFB around 150-200ms which is where I am aiming.

I've been trying to fix this for weeks and no luck.
Any advice is appreciated!
Thanks,

Martin

edit:

[img of how it looks like in devtools:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBzAV.jpg)
[img of sitemap load, crazy, right?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/298RW.jpg)

Comment: Without some debugging information, there is no way to help you. Look in your dev console at your network tab to see what is happening.

Comment: What kind of information? Let me know and I will look it up. I use chrome devtools to monitor TTFB.

Comment: If you're running a page builder like Elementor I wouldn't consider the site to be pretty light.  Page builders do a lot and include a lot.  That said, if the site's TTFB is slow even without the plugin active, then there's got to be some sort of configuration issue.  You'd have to provide as much information as possible to determine what it is.  What's your page count? (Not posts, but specifically pages.)

Comment: I have 0 post and 140 pages. Check out the second img I uploaded. It's just loading a sitemap.

Comment: Ok I just did a test: I created a blank page in WP, all plugins disabled. TTFB: 300 ms. What is being loaded if there is nothing?